# Sintax error, reglar parcialmente reconocida PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

me encuentro realizando un procedimiento sencillo en `PL/SQL` para practicar que recibe un numero  de entrada y salida y que lo incrementa cada vez que se ejecuta. El código es como este.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sumauno(suma in out int)
IS
BEGIN
SET suma=suma+1;
END;
```

en la instrucción `"SET suma=suma+1"` me marca un sintax error en el primer `suma`. Y no estoy  entendiendo porque.

muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

Tu error está en el uso de la palabra reservada `set` y el operador `=`. ¿Vienes de programar en `TSQL`?

En `PL/SQL`, para asignar el valor a una variable, no hace falta utilizar ninguna palabra reservada. El operador de asignación es `:=`, el `=` es un operador de comparación, tal como en el estándar `SQL`.

Por tanto, creo que lo que quieres hacer es esto:

```
suma := suma + 1;
```

La palabra reservada `set` existe, y se utiliza dentro de una sentencia `update`, o bien, cuando estás en *SQL*plus*, para asignar valores a las [*variables del sistema*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm),

Comment: si creo que si, pero la pregunta es que necesito guardar la suma para que se auto incremente cada vez que se ejecute. No se si tienes alguna idea.

Comment: ¿Guardar en una tabla?. Bueno, sería de hacer un `insert` o un `update`. Pero eso no era parte de la pregunta, no podría cubrirlo mi respuesta.